# How to make Tikz commutative diagram arrows have same vertical length

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I noticed something when working with `tikz-cd`. It isn't massive, but I wondered as to whether it was adjustable.

I am working with the current minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
        & \arrow[dl, swap, "R"] D \arrow[d, dashed, "F"] \arrow[dr, "T"] & \\
        B & \arrow[r, swap, "P"] B \times C \arrow[l, "Q"] & C
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I noticed that the middle, vertical arrow is not of the same height as the two diagonal, outer arrows. I wonder how I could make flush the bottoms of each arrow tip. Can this be adjusted with ease? I am slowly working through the docs, but haven't been able to work out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Arrows are default directed between center of nodes, so it can happen that they touch cells border on different places.
- For arrows you can specify `end anchor`. By selection appropriate anchors o their arrows, you can achieve what you after.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
                   cells={nodes={draw=gray, inner sep=2pt}} % to see cells borders, delete in real document
                   ]
        & \dlar["R" ', end anchor=north east] D \dar[dashed, "F"] \drar["T", end anchor=north west] & \\
      B & \rar["P" ']  B \times C \lar["Q"]           & C
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- The sam you do for starting of arrows, define `start anchor`. Using both, commutative diagram is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
                   cells={nodes={draw=gray, inner sep=2pt}} % to see cells borders, delete in real document
                   ]
        & \dlar["R" ', start anchor= south west,
                       end anchor=north east] D \dar[dashed, "F"] \drar["T", start anchor= south east,
                                                                             end anchor=north west] & \\
      B & \rar["P" ']  B \times C \lar["Q"]           & C
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:

- In real document delete diagram option for drawing cwells border.
- I wonder if adding this complexity is really worth to do.
- At sufficient long text in nodes arrows will end at top cell bordes without to define `end anchor`

Comment: Ahah! I see, thanks! I do recall seeing this at some point in Tikz. This is excellent and very informative, thank you :)